# Can I rearrange dll images in my .NET app's address space to make more contiguous free space available?

Tags: .net, out-of-memory, address-space

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/67f98ad782.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/67f98ad782.png)

This image shows fragmentation in my app's address space. Is there any way to force the (third-party) dll images (purple) together to eliminate (or mitigate) the fragmentation?

This app will run on 32-bit XP; obviously when we eventually move to 64-bit Windows 7, this problem will go away.

Thanks!

Comment: Awesome question. Are you referring to assemblies, unmanaged DLLs, or both?

Comment: Are you trying to solve a real problem or you just want to do it so it "look" cleaner?

Comment: The virtual memory fragmentation is not the physical fragmentation.  What real problem does this solve?

Comment: I think BlueRaja is correct: no memory is actually allocated for those gaps, so there is no cost.  Are you running out of address space?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I'm getting "out of memory" when trying to allocate a certain amount of memory, even though there's plenty of physical memory and address space available.

Comment: @David - it looks like there's both kinds of DLLs

Comment: @Christopher: Then, unfortunately, Brian Rasmussen's answer is correct.  Your best bet is to move to 64-bit sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can rebase your .NET assemblies, but the effect is rather limited as the JIT compiled code will be placed on the code heaps and that is not affected by rebasing. Also, from [Vista and forward the image loader randomizes loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) to prevent certain kind of exploits, so even if you rebase the assemblies will be loaded at random addresses.